# How to store multiple values on a django model field

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model where I store the recurring sessions on my gym.

```
DAYS_OF_WEEK = (
    (0, _("Monday")),
    (1, _("Tuesday")),
    (2, _("Wednesday")),
    (3, _("Thursday")),
    (4, _("Friday")),
    (5, _("Saturday")),
    (6, _("Sunday")),
)
class RecurringSession(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(SessionType,  db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dayofweek = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=DAYS_OF_WEEK)
    time = models.TimeField()
```

However some classes happen more than once a week. Whats the best way to store multiple values (between 1 to 7) on that modelfield?
I'm using Django Mysql 8.0, and from what I understand it supports JSON field but from the django docs it seems that is only supported by Postgres so far.
Is there a specific django way to do this? Maybe storing a charfield with comma-separated values?
I wont need to search by that field.

Every week, there will be a cronjob that will read this model and create an instance of each session on another model.
(I need each session as an instance for customization: teacher substitution, session roster, session status - i may cancel a single session on a bank holiday or for another reason).
So this "RecurringSessions" will be where I store the session information that will be generated every week.
The way that I wrote at first there will be an model instance for each day of the week of the same session, but I want to group them in the same instance because I think its looks nicer and may make it easier to set the teacher in bulk.
Alternatively, I could store a json with a dict for multiple day/time values for each session, however that would make it a little bit more difficult to make sure that if the cronjob is run twice the class doesnt get duplicated.

Now, to avoid that, I have a UniqueConstraint in my schedule model with fields "day", "time" and "room"

Using Django 3.0.6, Python 3.8.2, and MySQL 8.0.20.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to do a many-to-one relationship, so you'll either have to use this method [docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/), or if you want to avoid creating a database table and utilize Django's choice field, you can use this [extension](https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield).

Since there are seven fixed days in a week, I'll prefer the second method instead of creating a DB table, and unnecessary DB queries.

Comment: Thank you, I agree that extra databases queries are unnecessary at this point. So what this extension does is pretty much save a list of options in a charfield, right? whats the advantage of using this extension over doing it myself?

Comment: The library is more elaborate than a simple `day.split(",")`. For instance it’s got validators and Django admin integration. You can do it yourself for sure, but you’ll have to take care of several error checking aspects that you might not anticipate right now.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say the best structure without knowing what you're ultimately going to do with the model, however, I don't see why you couldn't have a single Session model that covers everything - like so:

```py
class Session(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (('C','Cardio'), #...and so on
    DAY_CHOICES = ((1,'Monday'), #...and so forth

    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    day = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=DAY_CHOICES)
    time = models.TimeField()
```

You could find the recurring sessions by counting the occurrences of a session once you've applied a filter to type or another field. That would keep your model structure concise and give you enough information in a single place to do filtering, annotation, etc. as required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I have just updated my question to explain exactly how I'm using that information.