# Saving and displaying multiple checkboxes to Django ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner on django 2.2 and I can't correctly send multiple choices in the database.
In my field table the days are stored like this:

```
['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
```

My form :

```
CHOICESDAY = (("Monday", "Monday"),
                  ("Tuesday", "Tuesday"),
                  ("Wednesday", "Wednesday"),
                  ("Thursday", "Thursday"),
                  ("Friday", "Friday"),
                  ("Saturday", "Saturday"),
                  ("Sunday", "Sunday")
                  )


class FgtScheduleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    days = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=True,
                                     choices=CHOICESDAY,
                                     widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(
                                         attrs={'class': 'checkbox-inline'}))

    class Meta:
        model = FgtSchedule
        fields = ('name','days')
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control form-form '
                         'shadow-none td-margin-bottom-5'}),
        }

    fields = ('name', 'days')
```

My model

```
class FgtSchedule(models.Model):
    days = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

My view :

```
def fg_schedule_list(request):
list_fg_sch = FgtSchedule.objects.all()
return render(request, 'appli/policy/fg_schedule.html',
              {'list_fg_sch': list_fg_sch})
```

My template

```
   {% for i in list_fg_sch %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ i.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.days|replace_days }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

My custom tags :

```
  @register.filter
def replace_days(value):
    CHOICESDAY = {"1": "Monday",
                  "2": "Tuesday",
                  "3": "Wednesday",
                  "4": "Thursday",
                  "5": "Friday",
                  "6": "Saturday",
                  "0": "Sunday"}
    return CHOICESDAY[value]
```

The problem is when I want to display later all the days I have `KeyError at "['1', '2']"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61723003/18406204

By using this [extension](https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield)!

I iterate like @LaCharcaSoftware said and it's working parfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that replace_days function is expecting a value like "1" and you are passing an array ['1','2']. You must to pass the values one by one or change the replace_days function.

You can change this line:

```
<td>{{ i.days|replace_days }}</td>
```

And do something like this:

```
<td>{% for day in i.days %}{{day|replace_days}}{% endfor %}</td>
```

Comment: yes I thouth something like that but same `KeyError at '[' ` I d'ont understand why multiple values stored in database field are retrieved as `['2', '3', '5', '6', '0']`. How can I have something like this when I created : 2,3,5,6,0 ?